# Вывод escape-последовательности из переменной

Tags: c++, c, строки

Есть строка которая берется из файла, и в ней содержатся escape-последовательности, например: `char *ptr="bla \n bla"!`
Если `printf("%s", ptr)` то будет с новой строки все, а я хочу чтобы вывелось все точно так же как строка. Есть идея бежать по строке и если по `ascii '10'` то печатать то что надо, `if` и прочее. Есть другие способы вывести нв стандартный вывод в точности как строка на Си и C++
Например на python выглядело бы так `print(repr(ptr))`

Comment: Вам надо вывести готовый строковый литерал или написать такой литерал? Ну, т.е. вариант `"bla \\n bla"` вас устраивает или нет?

Comment: Это не устраивает, вот есть переменная в которой уже лежит "bla \n bla", может что то другое, и это берется из файла и мне надо это вывести в неизменном виде

Comment: Тогда надо читать символы подряд и выводить с учетом таблицы управляющих символов...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, вам надо что-то [вроде этого](https://ideone.com/RoZnUd)?

```
void out(const char * s)
{
    for(;*s;++s)
    {
        char esc = ' ';
        switch(*s)
        {
        case 0x07: esc = 'a'; break;
        case 0x08: esc = 'b'; break;
        case 0x09: esc = 't'; break;
        case 0x0A: esc = 'n'; break;
        case 0x0B: esc = 'v'; break;
        case 0x0C: esc = 'f'; break;
        case 0x0D: esc = 'r'; break;
        case 0x5C: esc = '\\'; break;
        case 0x27: esc = '\''; break;
        case 0x22: esc = '\"'; break;
        }
        if (esc == ' ') putchar(*s);
        else { putchar('\\'); putchar(esc); }
    }
}
```

Comment: Да, только я думал есть ли другие варианты реализации, на python вот одна строчка, на си видимо если только так, на плюсах так же как на си?

Comment: После этого и на С одна строчка - `out(s)` :) Просто в питон запихано все, что только кому-то в голову приходило... Ну можно через таблицу реализовать - будет немного короче...

Answer (score 1):

Как написал Harry, можно и так:

```
void recode(const char* s) {
    for (; *s; ++s) {
        char code[] = "\x07\x08\x09\x0A\x0B\x0C\x0D\x22\x27\x5C";
        char* c = strchr(code, *s);

        if (c) {
            putchar('\\');
            putchar("abtnvfr\"\'\\"[c - code]);
            }
        else putchar(*s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Слабовато для полноценного 'escape()`. Вот, например, реализация: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/lib/string_helpers.c#L440

Comment: @0andriy Никто же не ставил задачу выводить, скажем, русские буквы как `\xCD` - да и это сразу приводит к неоднозначности. Стандатрные esc-последовательности и все.